# Mercurial Syncing only selective folders from Central Repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a central mercurial repository, and have many folders and code in there. I want to be able to sync only selective folders in my windows to be able to build the project and all folders in linux to build the same project n linux. Syncing all folders from central repository is easy

```
hg clone <repo address>/repo
```

but how do i sync only selective folders using the clone command

Something like Perforce's Workspace equivalent.

I guess we can write a script with some 'call' command, i tried googling for it, and could not find proper pointers to it.

Can somebody link me to it please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is [Mercurial's Subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository)

Comment: Awesome!! yeap, that should be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial doesn't work on a per-directory basis. It operates on changesets, and changesets are global to the repository. So, no, you cannot clone only one directory, you can only clone the entire repo.